# To show a video in android device when network is slow

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am developing an application where I need to display a bunch of videos from url which is comming from server side. I am using `VideoView` of Android for that purpose. Everything is working fine except if the network is slow, its taking nearly a minute sometime to load video in `VideoView`.

What i have done so far is displayed below. Please suggest some ways to make the video play little more efficient.

```
public class FullScreenVideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private VideoView mVideoView;
    private MediaController mMediaController;
    private Uri mUri;
    private ImageView mImageViewCloseWindow;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar = null;
    private int mPosition = 0;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        hideStatusBar();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fulllscreen_video);

        initView();
        initListener();
        checkBundle();
    }

    private void checkBundle() {
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String fragName = bundle.getString("fragmentName");
        if (fragName != null) {
            if (fragName.equals("CourseDetailFragment")) {
                mUri = Uri.parse(bundle.getString("URI"));
                showVideo();
            } else if (fragName.equals("ViewPagerFragment")) {
                mUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getApplication().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.mov_bbb);
                showVideo();
            }
        }
    }

    private void hideStatusBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        } else {
            View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

        }
    }

    private void initView() {
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        mMediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mImageViewCloseWindow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgCloseWindow);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

    }

    private void showVideo() {

        mVideoView.setMediaController(mMediaController);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(mUri);
        mVideoView.start();

    }

    private void initListener() {

        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int arg1,
                                                   int arg2) {
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mp.start();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        mImageViewCloseWindow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mVideoView.pause();
        mPosition = mVideoView.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mVideoView.seekTo(mPosition);
        mVideoView.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes video will take it's *buffer time* because you are displaying it from server and loading it. so better you use *buffer events* and put loader if video is *taking buffer* and otherwise if *buffer* done then play it.

Comment: Thank you for the response.Can u suggest some libraries which will handle things like Glide

Comment: I think you just need to use *mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener* you will get *buffer* events inside this. No need to use any other libraries.

Comment: I have added that already

Comment: Then what is the issue . you not getting *buffer events* in that ?